# Remix and Contract Factories

Tags: solidity, contract-design, remix, factory

I built out a fairly complex contract factory and I noticed the factory was only creating instances of itself, not the "child" contract.  After observing this I figured I was doing something wrong so I scaled back and tried to implement a super basic version first. However, I'm still observing the same behavior.  I wrote this in the Remix IDE and deployed it on the `Javascript VM` environment.

Here is my factory:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract ExampleContract {
    string public Name;

    function ExampleContract (string name) public {
        Name = name;
    }
}


contract Factory {
    address[] public contracts;

    function createContract(string name) public returns(address)  {
        address newContract = new ExampleContract(name);
        contracts.push(newContract);
        return newContract;
    }
}
```

Everything compiles and deploys fine.  When I use the `createContract` function it deploys a new instance of the `Factory` contract.  Am I missing something?

[image: example]

[image: gif]

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. I deployed `Factory`, then I called `createContract("test")`. Then I called `contracts(0)` to get the address of the new contract. I chose `ExampleContract` from the dropdown, pasted the address next to "At Address" and then clicked "At Address." I then had an instance of `ExampleContract`, and calling `Name()` on it correctly returned the string "test" (as I originally supplied to `createContract`).

Comment: hey @smarx thanks for the reply.  I included a GIF into my question. can you confirm we are performing the same actions but getting different results?  I switched over to a different machine/OS and was able to replicate my problem.

Comment: You failed to pick the right contract from the dropdown before clicking "At Address."

Comment: Ohhh. I was not aware you had to pick the contract from the drop down when using the `At Address` feature.  Noob mistake.  Seems obvious now. If you want to move your response to an actual answer I will mark it as correct.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments above, the issue was that the wrong contract was chosen when clicking the "At Address" button.